# Count and average specific values in a 2nd array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am looking to make a 2D array that averages only column and row index values that are divisible by 5. (So row 1, column 4, row 2, column 3, etc.). The array has 8 rows and 9 columns, mean of 1, sd of .5. Below is my best attempt but I get an error that more than one element is ambiguous.
Edit: clarity

```
def normalDistQuery():
    i = 8
    j= 9
    y = i + j
    normalX = np.random.normal(1,.05,(i,j))
    for y in normalX:
        if y % 5 == 0:
            continue
        totalNew =+ normalX(i,j)
        count =+ 1
    NewMean = totalNew/count
    print("the new mean based on index values is:", NewMean)
    
    
normalDistQuery()
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of input and output?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are attempting to take the modulo value of an array.

```
for y in normalX:
    # here y is equal to a row in the normalX array
    if y % 5 == 0:    # this doesn't work on an array
```

what you could do instead of the if statement is use `np.where(y % 5 == 0)` which would return a new array containing the index locations of values that pass the test, or simply implement another loop to iterate through each value in `y`.

Comment: I got it to work using this loop:

newNormal = normalX
    
    sum1 = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(newNormal.shape[0]):
        for j in range(newNormal.shape[1]):
            if(i+j) %5 == 0:

Comment: @Sam terrific  was I correct about why you were receiving the error?